# android - multiple content provider

Tags: android, apk, android-contentprovider

What is the best way to retrieve info from multiple Content Providers?
I'd like to crete new themes for my app and publish them as apk, but i won't edit the main app every time.
Each content provider will contain some bitmaps and a text font.
Is it possible to include xml layouts too?
This [app](http://www.zooper.org/wp/android/zw/apk) does something similar

Answer (score 0):

What about https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html ?
A contentprovider is an interface to access a database. I don't understand your question.